# How to avoid a function directing to another page if an entry is incorrect

Tags: javascript, php

I have a remove page where it can remove an entry from my database which is pre loaded into the option box. However, it redirects to my 'remove-module-complete.php' page when I type in any random text. I only want it to direct to the 'remove-module-complete.php' if their is that actual entry from the database. My javascript doesn't seem to be working.

I currently have some validation to say that the entry 'didnt match any item' from jQuery but it still directs me to 'module remove complete' if I press submit.

Any help?

Here is my PHP

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $moduleCode = $_POST['moduleCode'];
        $moduleCodeLen = strlen($moduleCode);

       if ($moduleCodeLen=6){

        $sqlTwo = "DELETE FROM MODULES WHERE id = '$moduleCode'";


        mysql_query($sqlTwo); 

        $resTwo =& $db->query($sqlTwo);
        if(PEAR::isError($res)){
            $errorVar = ($res->getMessage());
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid entry, please try again. Error code: $errorVar');</script>";
            die;  

        }
        else echo "<script> location.replace('http://project.ac.uk/remove-module-complete.php'); </script>";
    }
    else echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid entry, please try again');</script>";

}
?>
```

Comment: do you get error alert Invalid entry, please try again

Comment: $moduleCodeLen==6 not $moduleCodeLen=6

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some errors(commented lines):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $moduleCode = $_POST['moduleCode'];
    $moduleCodeLen = strlen($moduleCode);

    // '==', not '='
    if ($moduleCodeLen==6) {

        $sqlTwo = "DELETE FROM MODULES WHERE id = '$moduleCode'";

        mysql_query($sqlTwo); 

        $resTwo =& $db->query($sqlTwo);

        // there is no $res variable in the given part of the code
        // maybe you need to use $resTwo variable here?
        if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
            $errorVar = ($res->getMessage());
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid entry, please try again. Error code: $errorVar');</script>";
            die;  
        }
        else echo "<script> location.replace('http://project.ac.uk/remove-module-complete.php'); </script>";
    }
    else echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid entry, please try again');</script>";

}
```

Comment: re: `$res` ... I'm thinking it's actually a misspell of the `$resTwo` variable that is being initialized by the return of `$db->query($sqlTwo);`

Comment: @MichaelStilson, yes, thanks, I've updated the answer.